# Failure to edit a file hosted on Heroku using python

Tags: python-3.x, heroku

I have deployed my python script on Heroku. The script uses a for loop to iterate and it updates the file on every iteration. If the server goes down the script checks for the value stored in the file and it should continue the iteration from the point where it left. In this case, the script is restarting at 1 which is the value that I put when I deployed the script. If I run this script on my local machine and stop it is continuing from where it left of.

Below is the sample code

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
      with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
           file_data = file.readlines()
           count = file_data
      for i in range(count, some_long_number):
           with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
                file.writelines(str(i))
           time.sleep(900)
```

Comment: Quite possibly heroku doesn't keep your files around once the server is restarted. So you're starting off fresh every time there is a restart. Consider using a database or some sort of persistent storage.

Comment: Thank you, i did not know that the file is deleted every time there is a restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku has an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).
A container (very similar to Docker) is built whenever you deploy your app. It is then executed at runtime.

This means any file changes will not be preserved across app restarts or redeployments, hence your issue here.

You need to store your file counter in a persistent database such as PostgreSQL or Redis. Heroku offers those as add-ons.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that the file is deleted every time there is a restart. This was very helpful sir.